# Bibliography not printed using biblatex and natbib

Tags: biblatex, natbib, biber, cite-package

I have problems with making a reference list in Overleaf. I have created a `.bib` file with my references, but it won't print at all or it just the bib-file name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencer.bib}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}     
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cite}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={160mm,247mm},
 left=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\input{Forside.tex}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\input{Chapter1}
\input{Chapter2}
\input{Chapter3}
\input{Chapter4}

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't load `\usepackage{cite}`, `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\usepackage{biblatex}` together. You should only ever load one of the three. Judging by the other code in your preamble you should remove `\usepackage{cite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}`.

Comment: You may want to read up about `biblatex`, `natbib` and friends at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 might also be a good read.

Answer (score 3):

You can't load `\usepackage{cite}`, `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\usepackage{biblatex}` together. You should only ever **load one of the three**.

`biblatex` uses a completely different approach to producing citations and the bibliography than standard LaTeX/BibTeX. The packages `cite` and `natbib` were written to enhance the standard LaTeX/BIbTeX approach to citations and bibliographies, so they don't work together with `biblatex`. Since `cite` and `natbib` both do similar things, they shouldn't be used together to avoid definition clashes (for the most part `natbib` implements a superset of `cite`'s features). Some more background can be found in [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).

Judging by the other code in your preamble and document body, you are using `biblatex`, so you should remove `\usepackage{cite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}`.